# Null-coalescing and right-associative in C# - clarification?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I've seen a tweet about  the `null-coalescing` operator (which is right associative ):

*From the SPEC:*

> For example, an expression of the form `a ?? b ?? c` is evaluated as
>   `a ?? (b ?? c)`

So there was another guy which replied that it can be tested and verified with an example :

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine ((P)null ?? (string)null ?? "b555");
}

public class P
{
 public static implicit operator P(string b) {throw new Exception(b??"a");}
}
```

Result :

```
Exception: b555
```

But I didn't understand the behaviour.

**Question**

I already know that the `??` has a *very* low precedence  but still :

`(P)null` should evaluate *first* (higher precedence)  !

But it seems that

`a ?? (b ?? c)`

Is evaluated first.

Why ?

In other words , it seems that these are the events:

```
 (P)(null ?? ((string)null ?? "b555"))
```

And then :

```
(P)(null ?? "b555")
```

And then :

```
(P)"b555"
```

But I don't understand why `(P)` is applied on all the coalesce expression and not on the `null` ( in `(P)null`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should your implicit conversion be applied to `null` in  `(P)null`? `(P)null` yields a null-reference statically typed to `P`, why should any *conversion from string* be applied here? There is no mention of any string in `(P)null`.

Note how the compiler statically types the following expressions¹:

```
((string)null ?? "b555")   -> string

((P)null ?? ...some expression of type string...)    -> P
```

Thus,

```
((P)null ?? (string)null ?? "b555")     -> P
```

Now the expression can be resolved as follows:

1. `(P)null` is null, so we look at the right-hand side.
2. `((string)null ?? "b555")` yields the string `"b555"` (no P involved).
3. `((P)null ?? "b555")` results in a value of `"b555"`. Since the static type of `((P)null ?? "b555")` is `P`, `b555` is implicitly converted to `P`, triggering your implicit conversion.
4. We get an Exception "b555", as expected.

PS: If anyone is interested in a more detailed explanation in the form of a dialog, we have taken this topic to chat and [here is the transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/84978).

---

¹ Proof:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var x = ((P)null ?? "abc");
    x.A();   // compiles
}

public class P
{
    public static implicit operator P(string b) {throw new Exception(b??"a");}
    public void A() {}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your point number 2 : If `"b555"` is the value of  `((P)null ?? "b555")` , so we have only the string b555. And then you say   : _static type of ((P)null ?? "b555") is P_ ....?

Comment: Every expression has a (static) type. `1 + 2` has type int, `1 + 1.0` has type double. `(object)"abc"` has type object. The expression `((P)null ?? "b555")` has type `P`, since `"b555"` is implicitly convertible to `P`. Otherwise, if there were no implicit conversion, `((P)null ?? "b555")` would be compile time error, since no expression type could be infered.

Comment: In other words: The compiler silently extends `((P)null ?? "b555")` to `((P)null ?? (P)"b555")`, since ?? only works with operands of the same type.

Comment: The penny was dropped just  now. When the compiler sees `(P)null ?? "b555"` then it does a "b555" (string) to `P` conversion and in _that_ stage exactly the conversion happens. It is not the `(p)null` which triggers the exception , but the phase BEFORE which is trying to convert "b555" to P. Right?

Comment: It's very regular to understand when you see a foolish example like `var a=true?"a":"2";` which compiles as opposed to `var a=true?"a":6;`. Oh well....but still the implicit operator was the heart for this. Nice interview question BTW I must say.

Answer (score 1):

`(P)` is only applied to the first `null`. However, the class P has an implicit conversion from string to P, hence why it throws the exception. It doesn't need you to explicitly request a type conversion due to the `implicit` keyword.

Comment: Still , how the b555 got in there?

Comment: Basically, first the code evaluates `((P)null ?? (string)null ?? "b555")`

Obviously, `null ?? null ?? "b555"` yields "b555". However, since "b555" is a string, the compiler checks if P has an implicit conversion operator with a string parameter. Since it is defined, it's called with parameter "b555"

Comment: You make it sound like it like this : `(P)(null ?? (string)null ?? "b555")`

Comment: So basically, what happens is, first it evaluates `((string)null ?? "b555")` which returns a string, `"b555"`. Then it evaluates `(P) null ?? "b555"`; however since it compares a P with a string, it checks if a type conversion is possible. The compiler then finds the implicit operator (let's give it a temporary name) `StringToP(string s)` which returns P and is marked as default converter function for implicit conversion.

Thus it evaluates `(P)null ?? StringToP("b555")` which throws an exception as defined in StringToP's body.